# Oracle query to find largest value (gpa) from table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to query the name, major, and gpa of the students who have the highest GPA. There can be more than one student.

```
SELECT student_name, major, MAX(gpa)
FROM Student;
```

I keep getting:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

I Googled that I should either drop a group function (which I don't have, but tried adding) or add a group by clause that includes all individual column expression listed.

I've also tried the group by clause:

```
SELECT student_name, major, MAX(gpa)
FROM Student
GROUP BY student_name;
```

And I get the error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Can someone please point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix expressions which give a single line result per line in the table (e.g., in your case, `student_name` and `major`) and expressions that give a single line result per **a group of lines in the table** (i.e., aggregate functions, like `MAX(gpa)` in your case). How many lines should be outputted in such a case?

You need to break up your query into two logical parts - one finding the highest GPA, and the second finding all the students with such a GPA. One way of doing this is by using the aggregate expression in a subquery of an `IN` clause:

```
SELECT student_name, major, gpa
FROM   student
WHERE  gpa IN (SELECT MAX(gpa) FROM student)
```